# How can Google account credentials by applied to my PHP app (SSO)?

Tags: php, openid, single-sign-on, janrain, google-sites

I have a PHP application that will be accessed by users who are already
signed into Google  ( the app runs in an iFrame on a Google Site that
requires Google login)

What is the best SSO approach that uses Google login, so users have 
the same identity in both places?

Best to use a some OpenID opensource?  .. zend/cake/symf plugin? 
GoogleApps infrastructure?  .. or a identity service like Janrain?

Is it too early to go with OpenID Connect?    etc.

Thanks much.

Comment: It's called OpenID, and is used here at stackoverflow - you can log into SO with your google account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID works well - and indeed, is good enough for StackOverflow - you probably used it to register your account here.

There's an article called [Getting Started with OpenID](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581). Although it's on Zend's website, it doesn't seem to be tied to the Zend framework, so is a good starting point. It covers all the modules you need to download, and includes an example to help get you started.

Comment: This is a pretty fricken great article.. could very well help us turn the corner on our OpenID effort.. thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look on [simplesamlphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) and its integration with Google:

[Setting up a simpleSAMLphp SAML 2.0 IdP to use with Google Apps](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/trunk/simplesamlphp-googleapps)

Is an open source project based on php. Nice comunity and complete documentation.

Comment: this looks like very well done doc and their supporting SSO provider list is a pretty good set of credentials it seems.. +1 fer sure..

Answer (score 1):

Hi again I recently discovered this interesting project [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/), an SSO PHP Library for authentication through identity providers like Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo, LinkedIn, MySpace, Windows Live, Tumblr, Identica, LastFM, OpenID, PayPal, Vimeo, Foursquare, AOL, Viadeo, and others.

I didnt test it but seems also a good solution.